# xindy: rules file for arabic language?

Tags: indexing, arabic, xindy

Is there any rules file to process an index written in Arabic language? XeLateX generated this `.idx`-file.

```
\indexentry{ مجموعة الاعداد الطبيعية|hyperpage}{٣}
\indexentry{القيمة المطلقة|hyperpage}{٦}
```

Many thanks.

Comment: I used this language file `variant1-utf8-test.xdy` provided by xindy-persian package. To process index file I used this command: `texindy -M xindy-persian/variant1-utf8-test.xdy file_name.idx` But I had warnings : `page numbers and correponding entries were ignored. WARNING: location-reference "٣" did not match any location-class! (ignored)` 
How to tell xindy about page numbers e.x  "٣" which corresponds to page 3... In .tex file I use `polyglossia` and `fonspec` packages the arabic font is loaded with `Mapping=arabicdigits` option

Answer (score 1):

There is not any rules for Arabic. However, there is [`xindy-persian`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xindy-persian) package for Persian. Arabic being a subset of Persian, you can use the Persian language instead.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. 
I tried  xindy-persian package to process the index with this command : `texindy  -M xindy-persian/variant1-utf8-test.xdy  file_name.idx` 
But I have warnings : page numbers and correponding entries were ignored.
`WARNING: location-reference "٣" did not match any location-class! (ignored)`
How to solve this ?

Comment: I am not sure what package you use. But it is best to use western digits. By this, I mean you should have `\indexentry{ مجموعة الاعداد الطبيعية|hyperpage}{3}` instead `\indexentry{ مجموعة الاعداد الطبيعية|hyperpage}{٣}` and then xindy also understands it. I think you use Buggy polyglossia and perhaps its `arabicnumbers` package. You need to disable this.

Comment: And just use `Mapping=arabicdigits` as the option of your Arabic font; it converts western digits to corresponding Arabic ones on the fly.

Comment: I used language files provided by the xindy-persian package and  I alerady use the option ˋMapping=arabicdigits` for the Arabic font. How to make xindy undrestand arabic digits ?