# Index conflict with babel Package

Tags: babel, indexing

\For the shown, MWE I have an issue which that the index package (any of the indexes package: makeidx,imakeidx,xindy,xindex) does not generate the index upon compilation. However, Upon removing the option (layout=counters.lists.tabular) within the babel package. The file index is generated normally. Does anyone know a workaround this since I need such option in order to maintain numbering in the document to appear with the main document language.

```````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}
%General Settings
\usepackage[a4paper,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,margin=2.5cm,bindingoffset=0.5cm]{geometry} % Set paper layout

%==================================================================================================
%CROSS-Referencing
%==================================================================================================

\usepackage{makeidx}
    \makeindex

%======================================================================================================
%Babel Package Settings%
%======================================================================================================

\usepackage[nil,bidi=basic-r,layout=counters.lists.tabular]{babel}
\babelprovide[import=ar,mapdigits,main]{arabic}
\babelprovide[import=en,language=Default]{english}
\babelfont{rm}{Latin Modern Roman}
\babelfont[arabic]{rm}{amiri}
%==================================================
%Start actual document %
%===================================================


\title{jhhjjhhj}
\author{}
\date{}


\begin{document}
 يسبسيسيب
 سيبيسيبيسب
 سيبيسبسيبس
 سيبسيبسيب
\index{dfdfdf}
\end{document}
``````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
```````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````

Comment: Don't make so long examples. I at least have neither the time nor the will to install lots of fonts and read lots of unrelated code lines to answer a question. This here it is a question and answer site where people are helping in their free time. Take this into account.

Comment: @ Ulrike, Sorry for annoyment, I simplified the code.

Comment: Isn't this much the same as your question at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/506372/index-not-generated-in-an-arabic-document ?

Comment: @ David, The same however, I wasn't able to post the code above in the comments of the previous question, so I thought the discussion can be continued here. The previous one was resolved through the use of the bib2gls package, however, I believe that using xindex - xindy - imakeidx can be made possible if we figured out the conflict between such packages and the babel package option (layout=counters.lists.tabular), as  the issue was thought to be a conflict due to the use of unicode characters, while it might not be

Comment: As I already mentioned in one comment of your many questions: The problem is that babel changes the definition of \arabic and so the page counter has a form in the idx file that makeindex doesn't like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Update

Using `bidi=basic` allows us to dispense with `layout=counters`. This means we can run `xindy` without any of the below `perl` hacks.

This also shows how you might have two indexes for two languages.

Run

```
$ lualatex filename.tex
$ texindy -L persian-variant1 -C utf8 filename.idx
$ texindy -C utf8 filename-en.idx
$ lualatex filename.tex
```

The `texindy` commands are supposed to run automatically if you call `lualatex` with `--shell-escape`, but for some reason they don't for me :/.

### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[bidi=basic,layout=lists.tabular]{babel}
\babelprovide[import=ar,mapdigits,main]{arabic}
\babelprovide[import=en,language=Default]{english}
\babelfont[arabic]{rm}{Amiri}
\babelfont[english]{rm}{Latin Modern Roman}

\usepackage[xindy,nonewpage]{imakeidx}
\makeindex[options=-L persian-variant1 -C utf8]
\makeindex[name=\jobname-en, options=-C utf8]


\begin{document}
يسبسيسيب
\index{أَلِف}

يسبسيسيب
\index{بَاء}

يسبسيسيب
\index[\jobname-en]{Alpha@\foreignlanguage{english}{Alpha}}

يسبسيسيب
\index[\jobname-en]{Beta@\foreignlanguage{english}{Beta}}

\printindex
\selectlanguage{english}
\printindex[\jobname-en]
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

---

## Original answer

Difficult. And I don't really understand what is going on here.

This is what happens. With the `babel` option `layout=counters.lists.tabular`, an extra macro gets inserted into the `idx` file by `babel` with the page number. This causes the indexing programs to die. Perhaps `babel` should not do this.

So for `\index{أَلِف}` the `idx` file has a line in it like this:

```
\indexentry{أَلِف}{\babelsublr  {1}}
```

But we want it to look like this:

```
\indexentry{أَلِف}{1}
```

So, what to do? We could use a `perl` one-liner to edit the file:

```
perl -pi -e 's/\\babelsublr\s*?{(.*?)}/$1/'
```

For the actual index set up, I think you need to use `xindy`. Sadly I find `xindy` very difficult to understand and use. It's not very well documented and there are few examples. There are no Arabic rules, but some have [suggested](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/312048/87678) that it's possible to [xindy-persian](https://ctan.org/pkg/xindy-persian).

I do seem to be able to get semi-sensible results.

### MWE

I build this manually using the following commands:

```
$ lualatex filename.tex
$ perl -pi -e 's/\\babelsublr\s*?{(.*?)}/$1/' filename.idx
$ xindy -L persian-variant1 -C utf8 -M numeric-sort -M latex -M latex-loc-fmts -M texindy filename.idx
$ lualatex filename.tex
```

I get the `xindy` command line from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/454910/87678).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[bidi=basic-r,layout=counters.lists.tabular]{babel}
\babelprovide[import=ar,mapdigits,main]{arabic}
\babelprovide[import=en,language=Default]{english}
\babelfont[arabic]{rm}{Amiri}
\babelfont[english]{rm}{Latin Modern Roman}

\usepackage[xindy,nonewpage]{imakeidx}
\makeindex[noautomatic]

\begin{document}
 يسبسيسيب
\index{أَلِف}

يسبسيسيب
\index{بَاء}

يسبسيسيب
\index{Alpha@\foreignlanguage{english}{Alpha}}

يسبسيسيب
\index{Beta@\foreignlanguage{english}{Beta}}

\printindex
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

Comment: Regarding the [xindex] package, can it provide any further privileges??

Comment: @Silva, I'm not sure what you mean. Are you referring to the `xindy-persian` package?

Comment: https://ctan.org/pkg/xindex?lang=en

Comment: @Silva, maybe. Looks interesting, but I have never used it.

Comment: @ David, regarding the babel package, I do have 2 questions: Why is the nil option omitted. Also, regarding bidi=basic-r, it is mentioned in the babel package manual "Inluatex,basic-r provides a simple and fast method for R text, which handles numbers and unmarked L text within an R context many in typical cases.New 3.19Finally,basic supports both L and R text, and it is the preferred method (support for basic-r is currently limited).", so why not use bidi = basic since it says that support for basic-r is currently limited?

Comment: @silva, Looking at the `babel` manual I think `nil` is no longer needed. It used to be and I hadn't checked for a while. It seems to work OK (better?) without it. And yes, maybe using `bidi=basic` is better, especially since you are using many languages. Try and see?

Comment: @Silva, from the manual I take it that you could get rid of `counters` then which might give the right `idx` output.

Comment: Finally, regarding the solution for index issue, is there a tweak to make the page numbers appear on the RHS of the English indices instead of the LHS. And also can the page numbers appear as English with English text and arabic with arabic text?

Comment: @ DAvid, So the counters option can be cancelled while maintaining the numbering format

Comment: @Silva, I think so, yes. I would create separate indexes in different languages to get the numbers on the right for English.

Comment: HOw do I run this set of commands: $ lualatex filename.tex
$ perl -pi -e 's/\\babelsublr\s*?{(.*?)}/$1/' filename.idx
$ xindy -L persian-variant1 -C utf8 -M numeric-sort -M latex -M latex-loc-fmts -M texindy filename.idx
$ lualatex filename.tex

Comment: @Silva, Run them in a console. But see my update for simpler commands. I think it is better to use `bidi=basic` and remove the `counter` option.