# MWE for xindex package

Tags: indexing, xindex

I need a MWE regarding the use of the xindex package for generating an index, I am preparing a document with lots of unicode fonts, A solution has been proposed regarding the use of xindy package, [Index conflict with babel Package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/507066/index-conflict-with-babel-package/507102?noredirect=1#comment1281353_507102)

However, I was wondering if using the xindex package may allow avoidance of such tweaks. It is much better if  the use of such package is emphasized on the shown MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}
%General Settings
\usepackage[a4paper,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,margin=2.5cm,bindingoffset=0.5cm]{geometry} % Set paper layout

%==================================================================================================
%CROSS-Referencing
%==================================================================================================

\usepackage{makeidx}
    \makeindex

%======================================================================================================
%Babel Package Settings%
%======================================================================================================

\usepackage[nil,bidi=basic-r,layout=counters.lists.tabular]{babel}
\babelprovide[import=ar,mapdigits,main]{arabic}
\babelprovide[import=en,language=Default]{english}
\babelfont{rm}{Latin Modern Roman}
\babelfont[arabic]{rm}{amiri}
%==================================================
%Start actual document %
%===================================================


\title{jhhjjhhj}
\author{}
\date{}


\begin{document}
 يسبسيسيب
 سيبيسيبيسب
 سيبيسبسيبس
 سيبسيبسيب
\index{dfdfdf}
\index{يببيسيب}
\end{document}
```

Comment: xindex has currently imho only configuration files to sort western script. You would  have to add something for arabic first. Check the documentation.